# Closed-form solution of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am interested in a closed-form method for finding all solutions of the following trigonometric equation in $\theta$:

\begin{equation}
a\sin(2\theta) + b\cos(2\theta) + c\sin(\theta) + d\cos(\theta) \,=\, 0
\end{equation}

where $a, b, c$ and $d$ are given real numbers.

Comment: Start by combining this all into one sine function.

Comment: And then do what?

Comment: take inverse sine (all possible values) and rearrange. Not much different from solving quartic, but might look a tad cleaner if done right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z = \exp(i\theta)$, your left side is $$a(z^2-z^{-2})/(2i) +b (z^2+z^{-2})/2 + c (z - z^{-1})/(2i) + d (z + z^{-1})/2$$
After multiplying by $z^2$, you have a quartic in $z$.  Its roots can be expressed in closed form (though rather complicated).

Comment: Could you provide a reference for solving quartic **complex** polynomials? This would complete the answer.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)